# Driver "Transform space" option is mixing different rotations

Tags: animation, drivers

When frame is switching from 5 to 6, red monkey weirdly flips and green rotates well.
Red one is using empty's *X rot Transform space* as variable. Green - empty's *data path of X rot*.

Empty is keyframed for all rotation channels and it seems that Driver is mixing them like as *World space*
[image]

You can see how drastically driver value has changed (**from 2.896 to -0.246**), while empty was barely rotating
[image]

Is it a normal behaviour? And should I always stick to *data path* connection for driver in similiar cases?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure of the cause, if you clear the rotation of the empty and only rotate it on the x axis the issue stops.